# How to call the UsbDevice.getDeviceName() method - without error (cannot be referenced from a static context)

Tags: java, android, static, non-static

why will the following not work?

```
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;

public class work {
    public String getDeviceName(){
        return UsbDevice.getDeviceName();
    };
}
```

returns "getDeviceName() cannot be referenced from a static context.

How do I correctly call the UsbDevice.getDeviceName(); method?  - My class "work" is not static so why does this error appear?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object of `UsbDevice` and call the method from it.

```
UsbDevice usbDevice=//something;
String deviceName = usbDevice.getDeviceName();
```

eg:

**To get connecting devices realtime:**

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        UsbDevice usbDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        String deviceName = usbDevice.getDeviceName();

    }
};
```

**to get already connected devices:**

public void getConnectedDevices() {
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

```
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
    while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
        UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();

        manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
        String name= device.getDeviceName();

    }}
```